# Disable all default animation in JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx

I have some ghost animation in my app and I have no ideaes to remove it. You can see that animation on next GIF.

[image]

Animation of chart and axises are disable. Left part's structure is:

```
<TitledPane>
    <content>
        <AnchorPane>
            <LinearChart/>
            <Canvas/>
        </AnchorPane>
    </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Any ideas, why this is happening ? Can I remove only that animation ? May be exist way to disable all default animations ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is is very difficult to cut this part of code from project, becouse it have many dependences with data. I thought that questions like "how to disable all animation?" and "what view can cause animation?" don't require some code.

Comment: code is our common language and it's your _job_ to distill the essence of a problem into that language .. but if you don't want help *shrugs As to your assumed problem: I doubt that you can disable animations globally - what you can try though is to disable them via css by setting the .animated property where available

Comment: All you need to do is set the minWidth of the Parent node holding the Chart or the Chart. When the chart shrinks, it adjusts accordingly. If the Chart never shrinks, it will remain the same. I think setting the Chart's minWidth will produce the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: It work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a sample app that demos the behavior you are trying to achieve. In this app, I set the `Min Width` of the left `TitlePane's` `AnchorPane` to `300`.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication259 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    LineChart chart1, chart2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("Series 1");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1000, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2000, 100));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3000, 80));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4000, 180));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5000, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(6000, -10));
        chart1.getData().add(series1);
    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="581.0" prefWidth="908.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication259.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="7.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                    <children>
                        <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="74.0" text="untitled" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="300.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <LineChart fx:id="chart1" layoutX="-117.0" layoutY="-43.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <xAxis>
                                                <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                                            </xAxis>
                                            <yAxis>
                                                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                                            </yAxis>
                                        </LineChart>
                                    </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                            </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                    <children>
                        <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="127.0" layoutY="170.0" minWidth="300.0" text="untitled" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <LineChart fx:id="chart2" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="65.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <xAxis>
                                                <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                                            </xAxis>
                                            <yAxis>
                                                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                                            </yAxis>
                                        </LineChart>
                                    </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                            </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```